# How to compare two arrays of jquery objects and copy select differences?

Tags: jquery, arrays

How can I compare the array objects for differences and copy select parts?

I have two html lists.

```
<ul id="listOne">
   <li data-info="a" data-infoTwo="x">One</li>
   <li data-info="b" data-infoTwo="y">Two</li>
   <li data-info="c" data-infoTwo="z">Three</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listTwo">
   <li data-info="a">One</li>
   <li data-info="b">Two</li>
   <li data-info="d">Four</li>
</ul>
```

I push the lists into the arrays as objects.

```
var listOneArray = [];
var listTwoArray = [];

  $('#listOne li').each(function () {
     listOneArray.push(this);
  });

  $('#listTwo li').each(function () {
     listTwoArray.push(this);
  });
```

I want to compare the arrays for if the object data-info is a match in both arrays.

If the data-info is a match in each object of each array. I want to copy the data-infoTwo object info from the one object to the other.

So when I push the array back to the listTwo it would look like this.

```
<ul id="listTwo">
   <li data-info="a" data-infoTwo="x">One</li>
   <li data-info="b" data-infoTwo="y">Two</li>
   <li data-info="d">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: does it need to be in an array? I mean it would be much easier to do it using selectors!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
$('#listOne li').each(function () {
    $("#listTwo li[data-info=" + $(this).data("info") + "]").data("infoTwo", $(this).data("infoTwo"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

since you didn't answer my question in the comments, I assumed that you can do it using selectors, so here we go:

```
$('#listOne li').each(function(){
    var listOne=$(this);
    $('#listTwo li').each(function(){
        if(listOne.data('info')==$(this).data('info')){
            $(this).data('infoTwo',listOne.data('infoTwo'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to compare your two lists, why don't you just iterate over the elements you need to copy and fetch the target element from the second array ?

```
$('#listOne li[data-infoTwo]').each(function(){
    var info = $(this).data('info'),
        infoTwo = $(this).data('infoTwo');
    $('#listTwo li[data-info="' + info + '"]').data('infoTwo', infoTwo);
});
```